# What should I know before learning Node? ( Prerequisites )

Tags: node.js

I love programing.I decide to become a backend **Node** developer.
I only know HTML and Javascript and I have strong knowledge with it.

Now I wonder.Is there any prerequisites before I start with Node.js ?

Should I have to learn HTTP request ?
Or Ajax?

Comment: Go learn the autonomy of an HTTP request & pickup a database, MongoDB is a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you might already know that `Node` is a `Server-Side` language rather than how traditional JavaScript runs on the `Client Side`. With that being said you might want to understand, how V8 engine works and what [event loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) is, because that's the building block of Node.js

Next you might want to understand what `async await`,`promises` and `callback` functions are and how you can implement it within your solution.

After learning about those, you might want to get into Middlewares beacuse 99.99% of the time you would be using one most commonly used are ([express](https://expressjs.com/), [restify](http://restify.com/))

You might look a bit into [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/) (Node Package Manager). **Don't let Packages intimidate you because there are 100's and 1000's of packages out there for every need but you pick one according to yours and use it, make sure if you have good knowledge of JavaScript you can do anything**.

As you already mention you have good understanding of JavaScript, might I suggest brushing up on some JavaScript concepts like High Order Array Methods.

There are 100's of tutorial out there where you can learn Node.js, Might I suggest [Traversy Media](https://www.youtube.com/user/TechGuyWeb/featured), one of my favorite YouTube channel to learn.

P.S- I'm not expert in Node.js at all, I'm still learning but this is the path I took and it worked out great for me, please suggest any changes or things any one else want's to add. I'll also try to edit and add some points as I recall them.